# Expectation of a sample average at a random point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, average, sampling-theory

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_i(x)$ where $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,\dots,N$. Let $f_{B}(x)=\frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{i \in B }f_i(x)$ where $B \subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\times \{1,\dots,N\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is the following true?

$$
\mathbb{E}_B\Big[f_{B}\Big(g(x, B)\Big)-f\Big(g(x, B)\Big)\Big]=0
$$
If yes, how can we proof it? If not, can we find any relationship between them?

**How to sample $B$?**

Fix the size of $B$ as $S_B$ and then select $S_B$ elements from $\{1, \dots, N\}$ uniformly without replacement such that $|B|=S_B$.

**My try:**

Clearly, for any fixed $x$,
$$
\mathbb{E}_B\Big[f_{B}\Big(x\Big)-f\Big(x\Big)\Big]=0.
$$
However, when we evaluate functions at $g(x, B)$, handling the above is not easy since $g(x, B)$ is a random variable.
Can you please help me?

Comment: What does $\Bbb E_B$ mean ? Are you sure of the $B$ in $g : \Bbb R\times B \to \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: @justt: $\mathbb{E}_B$ is the expectation over all possible sets that $B$ can take on, i.e., ${N \choose |B|}$. Yes, I am sure, think of $g(x, B)=x-\gamma f'_B(x)$ for example for some $\gamma>0$.

Comment: ok, so $g : \Bbb R \times \mathcal P(\{1,\ldots N\}) \to \Bbb R$ rather.

Comment: Yes. I will revise it.

Comment: $E_B(f_B(x))=E_B(f(x))$ is usually *incorrect* and it really depends on the distribution of $B$. Do you assume that $B$ has a uniform distribution?

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ: elements in $B$ are drawn without replacement  and uniformly. I edited the statement.

Comment: It's not clear if $S_B$ is a given fixed number - or, if it's random, which its distribution.

Comment: @leonbloy: $S_B$ is fixed. I have stated that in the statement. If it is not clear, you can edit my question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Let me change a little the notation. Let $B=(b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n)$ where $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$. Let $B$ have uniform probability over the set ${\mathcal B} = \{ B : \sum_i b_i = s\}$. Clearly, $E[b_i]=s/n$

Then $f_B(y) = \frac1s \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \, f_i(y)$.

And, indeed, if $y$ is fixed, $E[f_B(y)]= \frac1s \sum_{i=1}^n E[b_i] f_i(y)=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(y)= f(y)$.

But

$$E[f_B(g(x,B))] = \frac1s \sum_{i=1}^n E[b_i \, f_i(g(x,B))] \tag 1$$

And

$$E[f(g(x,B))] = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[f_i(g(x,B))] \tag 2$$

If we assume that $b_i$ and $f_i(g(x,B))$ are independent (or at least uncorrelated) then we get the desired conclusion.

But, of course, that's a pretty big assumption.

It's difficult to say more without more information about $g(x,B)$

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is true for any given $g$. For example,with $n=2$, let's define $g$ by :

### $$\begin{array}{ccc}g(x, \emptyset) &=& 0 \\
g(x, \{1\}) &=& 0\\
g(x, \{2\}) &=& 1 \\
g(x, \{1,2\}) &=& 0\end{array}$$

As you said in some comment that $S_B$ is a fixed number, I choose for this counter-example $S_B=1$. Then the random variable $B$ has value $\{1\}$ with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$, and has value $\{2\}$ with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Then :

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\mathbb{E}_B\Big[f_{B}\Big(g(x, B)\Big)-f\Big(g(x, B)\Big)\Big]&=& \dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_{\{1\}}\Big(g(x, \{1\})\Big)-f\Big(g(x, \{1\})\Big) \right) \\
&&+\dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_{\{2\}}\Big(g(x, \{2\})\Big)-f\Big(g(x, \{2\})\Big)\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_{\{1\}}(0)-f(0) \right) \\
&&+\dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_{\{2\}}(1)-f(1)\Big)\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_1(0)-\dfrac{f_1(0)+f_2(0)}{2} \right) +\dfrac{1}{2}\times\left( f_2(1)-\dfrac{f_1(1)+f_2(1)}{2}\Big)\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{f_1(0)-f_2(0)}{4}+\dfrac{-f_1(1)+f_2(1)}{4}\\
\end{array}$$
ans this quantity has absolutely no reason to be equal to $0$ (one can take $f_1(x)=0$ and $f_2(x)=x$ to conclude the counter-example).